# How to fix this error in programmatically (with trigger) active() the last occupied row in a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Supose you have a sheet with several hundred rows long. You could to this to go to the last row and start your work:

> 1) after opening the spreadsheet, do Ctrl End; Ctrl leftArrow; Ctrl
>   upArrow
>        this will take you to the last occupied row cell in column A 2) before closing the spreadsheet, select the last occupied cell in
>   column A and assign it range name endRow then when you open the
>   spreadsheet do Edit > Named ranges then click on endRow this will take
>   you to the last occupied row cell in column A;

I just find a way to programmatically implement this, it's really simple, but worked only in the oldspreadsheet. I just put this line inside `onOpen()` trigger and just works fine: `activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getLastRow(), 1).activate();`.
But it didn't work in the new Google Sheets (a new one with some thousands of rows). 
So, I tried the Zig advice, write this function:

```
function goToLastRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = s.getRange(s.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  range.activate();
 }
```

And set the trigger manually (`Script Editor>>Resources>>Triggers from this project>>Ad new trigger`). But it still didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: [bad news](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928)

Comment: Good news. Its solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this way to accomplish what you need:

`function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideRows(1,sheet.getLastRow());
 }`

This hides all rows with data from the active sheet, places the cursor on the next (empty) row, so you can start typing away.
when done with the row, simply click the little triangle to the left of the hidden rows, and they will reappear if you need so.
Might cause problems if more than one person enters new rows at the same time.

★ Here is another cool way to accomplish this without any scripting, plus works even with simultaneous users (the script version above could hide a row being entered if another person opens the spreadsheet with edit permissions.)

This 2nd no-script solution will only work if your data has a column with a fixed set of values (¹), for example a column with only the possible values 'pending', 'doing' and 'done'. So find such column, which I assume its on column 'A' in this example.

➮ Lets use "Filter Views" in the "Data" menu (only in the new sheets versions.)
This feature allows for personalized filters that only the user applying them sees. Create a filtered view called "Enter new rows mode" with no values checked for column 'A' (click filter:"clear" when you drop-down the column filter menu).

➮ Now, when you enter the spreadsheet, the filtered view is applied automatically and all rows with data will go away.
Start typing away. If other users start entering new rows, your row only goes away for them, not for you until you refresh the browser window.

➮ If other users remove the filtered view, its removed only for them, not for you.

You can also do something similar with the "old" filters but it has the same dissadvantage as the script solution regarding multiple users.

*¹ A fixed set of values is needed because the spreadsheet filters automatically add new items as checked in the view. You cant use a date column because you will always get new future values.
To configure the filter you need to already have at least one row per possible value, so that you can uncheck them in the column filter.
If new values are later entered, you need to edit the view to uncheck it.

Comment: B.R.I.L.L.I.A.N.T.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @ZigMandel and @Sergeinsas! Guys, what is the best place to look for a GAS programmer interested in a partnership?

Comment: (B.R.I.L.L.I.A.N.T)^B.R.I.L.L.I.A.N.T

Comment: you will probably find them here on s.o. i dont know of other group. Look here maybe http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers

Comment: so if I provide two solutions do I get two bounties? :)

Comment: @craftApprentice somehow the bounty is not going through. I believe it needs to be given before it expires?

Comment: I just discovered that! Thanks for tell me that!

Answer (score 0):

I just find the way, it's really very simple, just put this line inside `onOpen()` trigger and just works fine: `activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getLastRow(), 1).activate();`.
But it didn't work in the new Google Sheets. 
So, I tried the Zig advice, write this function:

```
function goToLastRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = s.getRange(s.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  range.activate();
 }
```

And set the trigger manually (`Script Editor>>Resources>>Triggers from this project>>Ad new trigger`).

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to add the trigger manually. This is done because if you just use the onOpen, it has many restrictions that manually added ones do not.

Comment: I'm trying onOpen() in a new google sheet and it isn't working. I tried add it manually (using the resources), but it still is not working.

Comment: I removed my answer as it actually didn't work on new SS... I didn't notice the sheet I used to test it was an old one ;)

Comment: I've spent quite a lot of time on this, I've tried everything I knew but it seems to be another bug for the issue tracker. The onOpen fires but the sheet doesn't update unless (for example) you go to the menu to open the script editor... nothing logic  in that behavior. I didn't find anything in the issue tracker about that either, I'm afraid you will have the honour to start a new one and I'll star it with pleasure ;)

Comment: Thanks, master @Sergeinsas. I'll do that as soon as possible. Until that, I'll use an old spreadsheet.

Comment: I guess you've seen Fabricator's comment... that's indeed bad news but it's also good news since there are quite a lot of stars on this issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change `getActiveSpreadsheet` to `getActiveSheet`. The spreadsheet is all the file, a sheet is just a sheet :P. But you will find that you cant go to any part of a spreadsheet in an `onOpen` trigger.

The best way is to create a menu for this.

At the end the code goes like this:

```
function onOpen() //the same to create a onOpen trigger
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Go to").addItem("Last Row", "goToLastRow").addToUi();
}

function goToLastRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(s.getLastRow());
  var range = s.getRange(s.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  range.activate();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question...from a menu it works easily but he was asking to do it automatically in an onOpen  triggered function.Have you tried to make it happen on opening?

Comment: As mentioned above by Fabricator's comment, [this is a known issue - 3928](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928)

Comment: It's a wont fix issue, so if he isn't going to trigger with a timer trigger he has to access it somehow. Because in the new spreadsheets you can't manually trigger a function if it isn't in a menu or its a function that you call to perform an action in a cell.